# Inner class - final variable can't be looped?

Tags: java, android, nested, inner-classes

I'm trying to make a loop that gives each button a method with a parameter dependent on what button it is. I keep getting the error:

> i is not a final variable - must be if nested in an inner class.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
    buttons[i].setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // issue is with i value here
            move.makeMove(move.cups.get(i);
            updateButtons();
        }
    });
    currentCup = nextCup;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
    final int currentI = i;
    buttons[i].setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // issue is with i value here
            move.makeMove(move.cups.get(currentI);
            updateButtons();
        }
    });
    currentCup = nextCup; 
}
```

Comment: That's strange - I tried this before and didn't work - must have made a syntax error... Thanks

Comment: @JossMillerTodd You might have declared your final variable inside the listener instead of outside. Or in the for loop.